# What would be a good architecture to trigger distributed asynchronous processing from a Django application?

Tags: python, django, linux, shell, architecture

I'm goind to build a Django application that provides a REST api to add some processing jobs.

On each request, a job is added to a database for processing later.

Jobs can be processed by custom commands (`./manage.py runJobs`)

Those jobs are CPU intensive, so if I'm running on a machine with 4 cores, 
I'd like to have *at most* 4 workers running jobs in parallel.

If I need to scale, I'll need to bo able to run more os the same workers on a different machine.

Processing jobs uses a lot of memory, so it's probably better to create a new process for each job - that is - I think it's better that `./manage.py runJobs` run *one job* and exits, rather than run many jobs in the same process.

I need to make sure that racing conditions won't cause two workers to get the same job.

I'm not very familiar with communicating between linux processes, so I thought it would be a good idea to come here for tips.

What architecture do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a job for http://gearman.org/

Comment: Since you are working Python/Django already, I'd recommend taking a look at [django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html). As far as the architecture itself is concerned, I'd recommend using a work queue similar to the [this one](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) (from the RabbitMQ website).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a good enough solution that allows me to use the database as a semaphore, and doesn't required me to install additional software on the server.

It gos like this:

------ The custom command ------

```
from django.db import transaction

def run_one_job():
    candidate_jobs = Job.objects.filter(status='PENDING')
    job = lock_one_job_from_list(candidate_jobs)
    if job:
        process(job)  # whatever that means
        job.status = 'DONE'
        job.save()

def lock_one_job_from_list(jobs):
    for job in jobs:
        _job = attempt_lock_job(job.id)
        if _job:
            return _job


@transaction.commit_on_success
def attempt_lock_job(id):
    j = Job.objects.select_for_update(id=id)[0]  # wait until you get a write lock for that record
    if j.status == 'PENDING':
        j.status = 'RUNNING'
        j.save()
        return j
```

------ worker.sh -------

```
while [ 1 ]
do
./manage.py runJobs
sleep 1
done
```

Then I can spawn as many worker.sh instances as cores are available.
This is not ideal because there will be a bunch of workers polling the database every second,
but it does solve the biggest risk: running the same job twice.
I'll think I'll go with this :-).

Please let me know if you see any holes in this approach.